# Can you cast a spell between extra attack attacks?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, combat, attack, spellcasting

If I had the extra attack feature, could I make the 1st attack, cast a BA spell (or action surge to cast an action spell), and then make the 2nd attack?

Comment: I've marked your question as a dupe because I think it has been asked before. This isn't a bad thing as this question might help others find that one. If that question doesn't answer it for you, please clarify for us how and why, and we'll see what needs to be done to help you.

Comment: Oh, and Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!